# Monitoring a large log file in C#

Tags: c#, file, monitoring

I have to monitor a large log file during the day with C#. The size goes up to 200-300 MB for a day.
What is the most efficient way to analyze it?
 
The file is locked by the producing program. Preferably I would either have a read which realises that lines have been added or would read backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) and [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You will never achieve good results with `C#`.

I created application in `C++` and I used `MFC String` to search `1GB` file. 
It takes about **15-20 seconds**. After that I used `char` type and it takes about **3 sec**!!!!

`C#` has lot of overhead and if you need really fast solution, use `C++` and `TCHAR`, `char`, data type.

Answer (score 0):

Change log rotation to a smaller value and then process the rotated logs - or - Process the whole log file the first time and remember the fileoffset / line for the next checking interval.